# How to flatMap Scala collection and retain original value in the result?

Tags: scala

Consider a function `f : A -> Option[B]`.

I want to flatMap using `f`, but keep the original value in the result as well, as a pair of values `(A,B)`.

I can write it like this:

```
collection.flatMap(a => {
  f(a) match {
    case Some(b) => Some((a,b))
    case None => None
  }
})
```

But is there a nicer way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
collection.flatMap(a => f(a).map(b => (a,b)))
```

Comment: Or just `a => f(a).map((a,_))`

Comment: Of course!. It's so obvious. That turned my messy looking code into a neat one-liner.

Comment: Or just `a => f(a).map(a -> _)`

Comment: @Suma Nice. There always seems to be a simpler way of doing things with Scala, though I'm not sure whether that is a good thing or a bad thing!

Answer (score 6):

This also works.

```
for {
  a <- collection
  b <- f(a)
} yield (a,b)
```

Comment: Nice. Much clearer than the other options.

Comment: Note: after desugaring for comprehension in this answer you get the code from Jatin's answer.